# MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toObjectId'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
db.collection('my_collection').aggregate([
    { $match : { $and: [ { _deleted : false }, { UserId : UserId } ] } },
    { $addFields: { _someId: { $toObjectId: "$SomeId" } } },
])
.toArray();
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

For every aggregate pipeline operator getting same error **MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$OperatorName'**

```
MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$toObjectId'
      at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/bhanwar/myproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:451:1)
      at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
      at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
      at processMessage (/home/bhanwar/myproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:1)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/bhanwar/myproject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:1)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
      at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: $toObjectId introduced in MongoDB 4.0 please make sure you are using the same.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was mongodb version issue.